# Do mass update on the table based on two different IDs

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to do a mass update on my table `tbl`

This how the table looks like when I do a select statement

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
```

It returns this:

[image]

What I'm trying to accomplish is to do a single update where UID are different but CID are the same. If this criteria is true update the second UID and set it with the first UID and set the OLDUID where UID was updated with the same UID.

So the output will be like this:

[image]

What I'm trying to accomplish here is if I do a select statement:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl where UID = 1
```

It should return both rows. I have tried to join the two table and then do the update, but every time I try to do a select statement before the update it returns more rows than expected.

Any suggestions?

**NOTE*** this is just a sample table. The original table contains thousands of rows. Also there're will be times where I will have 3 or 4 different UIDs but ONE CID. The concept is still the same. Update the two rows with the first UID and set the OLDUID with the ones that were updated.

**UPDATE:**

There're cases where two rows will have the SAME CID but UID are also the SAME. In this case, I don't want to update and set the OLDUID.

Here's an example:

[image]

Here's the output:

[image]

In this case it should ignore and do nothing. All of the rows where UID = OLDUID are the same type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a cte and the `ROW_NUMBER()` function as well as a windowed `MIN()`:

```
with cte AS (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY CID ORDER BY UID) RN
                      ,MIN(UID) OVER(PARTITION BY CID) Min_UID
              FROM Table1
              )
UPDATE cte
SET OLDUID = UID
   ,UID = MIN_UID
WHERE RN > 1
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5fa83/3/0)

**Update:**
To handle the additional case where the UID is the same and you don't want to update it, you can just add to your `WHERE` criteria:

```
with cte AS (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY CID ORDER BY UID) RN
                      ,MIN(UID) OVER(PARTITION BY CID) Min_UID
              FROM Table1
              )
UPDATE cte
SET OLDUID = UID
   ,UID = MIN_UID
WHERE RN > 1
  AND UID <> MIN_UID
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6f84d/2/2)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It seems that it's working, but I'm seeing something strange. I see a case where `UID = oldUID`. There shouldn't be a case like that. Any ideas?

Comment: @user1426542 That shouldn't happen, can you provide a sample when that occurs?  If there are additional fields that are needed to uniquely identify a group you should add those to the two `PARTITION BY` clauses.

Answer (score 1):

does this work?

```
UPDATE
    tbl
SET olduid = uid, uid = min_uid
FROM
    tbl INNER JOIN
    (SELECT
        cid,
        MIN(uid) AS min_uid
    FROM
        tbl
    GROUP BY
        cid) mn ON
    tbl.cid = mn.cid AND
    tbl.uid <> min_uid
```

fyi, returns same results on SQL Fiddle above

Comment: I haven't tried yet. But +1 for contribution. Thanks